# Find the lines in the text file

Tags: python, list, line

You will implement function index() that takes as input the name of a text file and a list of words. For every word in the list, your function will find the lines in the text file where the word occurs and print the corresponding line numbers (where the numbering starts at 1). You should open and read the file only once.

I have been only able to count the occurrence once.

```
def index(filename, words):
    infile = open(filename)
    content = infile.readlines()
    infile.close()
    count = {}
    for word in words:
        if word in count:
            count[word] += 1
        else:
            count[word] = 1
        for word in count:
            print('{:12}{},'.format(word, count[word]))

    Output :index('raven.txt',['raven'])
        raven       1,
    Desired Output : index('raven.txt',['raven'])
       raven 44, 53, 55, 64, 78, 97, 104, 111, 118, 12(No of lines it appear)
```

Comment: You redefine `word` in the second for loop ...

Comment: No, I *will not* implement the function `index()`. You can't tell me what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but It should work

```
def index(filename, words):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            for word in words:
                if word in line:
                    return "%s at line %i" % (word, i + 1)

print index("some_filename", ["word1", "word2"])
```

Or to avoid nested for loop :

```
def index(filename, words):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for line, word in itertools.product(enumerate(f), words):
            if word in line[1]:
                return "%s at line %i" % (word, line[0] + 1)

print index("some_filename", ["word1", "word2"])
```

And using list comprehension :

```
def index(filename, words):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        return "\n".join("%s at line %i" % (word, line[0] + 1) for line, word in itertools.product(enumerate(f), words) if word in line[1])

print index("some_filename", ["word1", "word2"])
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but i am not getting any output on it.

Comment: It's just a function ... Maybe you should call it ? And I think you should think a bit by yourself ...

Comment: A for loop in a for loop is not realy neat.

Comment: What do you propose better? I can use list comprehension but I think it's unuseful for printing ...

Answer (score 1):

going over the same problem probably.. i wrote the below..

```
def index(filename, lst):
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    content = infile.readlines()
    infile.close()

    for word in lst:
        print(word, end = '\t')
        for line in range(len(content)):
            if word in content[line]:
            print(line+1, end= ' ')
        print()

index('raven.txt', ['raven'])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this example:

File1.txt

```
Y
x
u
d
x
q
```

Code:

```
word='x'
i = 0
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        i = i +1
        if word in line:
            print(i)
            print('Found It')
```

In this example you read in a file, and look through it line by line. In every line you look if a word is presend. If that is the case we print something on the screen.

Edit: 
Or in a definition it would be:

```
filename='file1.txt'
word='x'
def index(filename, word):
    i = 0
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            i = i +1
            if word in line:
                print(i)
                print('Found It')

index(filename, word)
```

Comment: You can use `enumerate()` to get the line number. I think it's more pythonic. Your code doesn't answer to the question.

Comment: My code does answer the question, and I quote: 'find the lines in the text file where the word occurs and print the corresponding line numbers'.

Comment: Yes but the function shoud take a list of words as input